# SAS E Guide 5.1 creating additional '/' in file path

Tags: sas

Back story: I'm trying to export files using SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1. I've done so successfully for quite a while. I have tons of SAS programs that run everyday without issues, but recently I've noticed SAS adding additional slashes (/) in file paths, and then claiming that the path is wrong. One of my SAS programs that has ran daily for months, without being edited at all, has developed this problem out of no where! Nothing changed in the code!

Here is the log from my latest export attempt that is having the same issue:

```
     %PUT REPORTDATE = %sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-1),date7.);
     REPORTDATE = 16AUG15


     %LET FILE = filename_REPORTDATE..xlsx;



     PROC EXPORT
        DATA = finalData
        OUTFILE = "filepath/&FILE"
        DBMS = xlsx
        REPLACE;
        SHEET = "Sheet1";
     RUN;

     ERROR: Temporary file for XLSX file can not be created -> 
     /filepath//filename_REPORTDATE..$$1.  Make sure the path name is correct 
     and that you have write permission.
```

So, the path isn't correct, and I don't have permission......because it doesn't exist with that extra /.

If any SAS wizards could shed some light on this, I'd appreciate it!

EDIT: 'filepath' is not a macro, I just removed the actual file path for privacy reasons. It is a written out path, "/foo/bar/&FILE"

Comment: `filepath` is a written-out fixed path, or is a macro variable?  And, what version of SAS are you running (not EG version, but base SAS version)?

Comment: have you recently experienced some upgrades in SAS Base environment?

Comment: Is your actual code using a macro variable instead of a fixed path? If so then perhaps the macro variable is now being created with the trailing slash build in.  `%let path=~/mydir/;` instead of  `%let path=~/mydir;` .

Comment: Are you sure the file path exists? AFAIK SAS will ignore double // in the path name and export to the expected path.

Comment: @Reeza I know that's true in Windows, not sure about in Unix/linux.

Comment: @Tom and Joe, the file path is fixed and written out. I just placed 'filepath' in there for now to keep this as generic as possible and protect privacy. Sorry for not specifying in the main question. I'll add an edit.

Comment: @joshua are the extra periods in the path and $ actually there?

Comment: What do you get in the log from %put "/foo/bar/&file" ;  ?  Do you have this problem only when submitting code via EG?  Is it just proc export having this problem? Can you successfully run a data _null_ step that writes a text file /foo/bar/&file ?

Comment: Is the second `filepath` identical to the first, or is it a temporary directory?  And, again, what version of SAS are you running (including maintenance release)? 9.4 TS1M2?

Comment: @Reeza I just quadruple checked. It exists.

Comment: I just tested in Unix and Windows, extra / DO NOT stop SAS from exporting a data set, it ignores the extra /. The issue is somewhere else, an access issue, file created and opened issue or invalid name.

Comment: @stat there weren't any upgrades that mean team has been aware of.

Comment: You can have as many extra `/` or  \ as you want when specifying path names in SAS.  You can have three or four and it doesn't even blink. In fact, you can even interchange `/` with \ and it will still work!  It's a nice feature because you never have to remember whether you already added a slash to the end of the string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue on both problems I had mentioned.

First, the main issue: SAS appears to be case sensitive with file paths. The actual folder had capital letters in the name. I was pointing SAS toward the same file path, but in lower case letters. I realize you could not have seen this given my question, but to protect privacy, I had to remove the actual file path.

Second: I mentioned a job that had been running for months and suddenly developed the same problem. The file path was solid, but the file it was producing on a regular basis had grown over time to be over 200MB. I tried exporting that same data that was going to xlsx to csv instead, and everything works.

I'm not sure if this is a well known 'thing' with SAS, being case sensitive with file paths, or not exporting to xlsx for larger files. (I would have swore I exported larger files in the past!). I would lean toward saying that, while this does appear to be user error, SAS's errors didn't seem to point me in the right direction of solving the problem.

Thanks for everyone's efforts, I do appreciate it!

Comment: SAS in *NIX is case-sensitive in several ways (not an issue in Windows).  As you have already found out, filenames is one of them.  The autocall macro library is another (the case of the filename, the macro declaration, and the macro invocation must all match).  For this reason, always good practice to keep things in lowercase, then you never have to think about it.

Comment: @RobertPenridge re autocall macros in *nix,  the file name must be lowcase. But macro declaration and invocation can be mixed case, and do not have to match. @ Joshua, Generally *NIX file paths, file names, and commands are case sensitive, Windows are not. It's not really a question of whether SAS is case sensitive or not.  SAS is relying on the OS.